# Leap Motion Tremor Recognition?

Tags: java, processing, leap-motion

I'm a fairly new developer that has been working on stuff using Leap Motion for Processing https://github.com/voidplus/leap-motion-processing. I'm enjoying Processing thus far.

I came across this demo on YouTube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7o1v7RayEV8&feature=youtube_gdata

I need to build something like this but I have no idea where to start?! I cant even tell what language this app is built in and I cant find any documentation for it online....

If anybody could provide some pointers in the right direction it would be great! i'm going to continue to lurk the internet for more information....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build this in just about anything you like - Processing included. If you've already been using the Leap Motion API you should already know how to read the relevant values, so the rest would be a case of recording them over a period of time (perhaps into arrays or objects?) and then generating charts and statistical calculations on that data.

A good starting point for seeing which parameters can be usefully read from the Leap Motion can be seen here: http://js.leapmotion.com/examples/parcoords.html
This demo also includes sourcecode so you can quickly see how the values are being accessed from the API and handled.

(Note: this is written in JavaScript and uses ThreeJS, so best to view with a modern browser.)

Comment: Hey thanks, can you check that link? Looks like it doesn't work